# Create Branch in one repository from second repository file

Tags: git

I have two repo: `repo1` and `repo2`.

I cloned `repo2` only (have access for both repositories).

Now I am on `Repo2`.

I run this command to get specific file (file.json) from repo1 into repo2:

```
git archive --remote=git@repo1.git HEAD file.json | tar -x
```

The file was added into `repo2`, so I edited `file.json` and would like to create branch (for PR) on repo1 with this file.

How can I do it?

I guess that I need to add it as remote:

```
git remote add repo1 repo1.git
```

And maybe do something like:

```
git pull repo1
git checkout -b repo1/myNewBranchName
git add file.json
git commit -m 'update file.json'
git push
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You just need to clone `repo1`, edit the file, make a new commit, and push the commit. `repo2` does not seem to have anything to do with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a management system that is found in repo2. It gets json file and you can manage it.
That's why I want to pull this file from repo1, put it in repo2 and then push it back to repo1.